# Why I got a null when using jena QuerySolution

Tags: java, sparql, jena

My code:

```
String queryString = 
            "SELECT ?subject" +
            "WHERE { ?subject ?property ?object}";
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,model);
    ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

    // Output query results 
    //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
    while(results.hasNext()){
        QuerySolution sol = results.nextSolution();
        Resource subj = (Resource)sol.get("subject");
        System.out.println("subject:" + subj.getURI());
    }
```

I want is to output all the subjects in my knowledge graph, However, it reported `null pointer error` when executing the print sentence, and I found that it was because of subj is a null.

Maybe it was caused by the wrong use of the get method of QuerySolution.

Comment: I have fixed it by modifying the SPARQL sentence by SELECT * instead of SELECT ?subject. But I still don't understand why.

Comment: Missing space after `?subject`. Your query would be `SELECT ?subjectWHERE { ...` A parser won't fail as the keyword `WHERE` is optional. And that means there would be a projection variable `?subjectWHERE`

Comment: @AKSW Thanks. You can answer this question and so that I can accept it